# onclick and change innerhtml

Tags: onclick, click, innerhtml

I want to click in my buttons and when I clicked on each button => p.innerhtml = each div that clicked in that button.

```js
<script>

    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("b");
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function (event) {
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML
        };
    }

</script>
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
    <div class="g" id="11">100</div>
    <button id="1" class="b">btn</button>
    </div>
<br>
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div class="g" id="12">200</div>
    <button id="2 " class="b">btn</button>
</div >
<br>
<div style="display: flex">
    <div class="g" id="13">300</div>
    <button id="3 " class="b">btn</button>
</div>




<p id="name"> name</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

add "-10" for id of div's

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("b");
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function (event) {
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = document.getElementById(this.id-10).innerHTML
        };
    }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="g" id="1">100</div>
  <button id="11" class="b">btn</button>
</div>
<br>
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="g" id="2">200</div>
  <button id="12 " class="b">btn</button>
</div>
<br>
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="g" id="3">300</div>
  <button id="13 " class="b">btn</button>
</div>




<p id="name"> name</p>
```